# How to escape quotes in arg passed to program

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch-file

So I have following problem. I have batch script `script.bat` having folowing content

```
cat %* | gawk " { value = "something" } "
```

Which obviously does not work. In bash, I would escape the quotes inside a quotes to `" { value = \"something\" }"`. Or even changed `"` to `'`. However windows does not have such feature (`'` is just normal character). I looked for a solution and found two ways.

```
cat %* | gawk " { value = ^"something^" } "
cat %* | gawk " { value = ""something"" } "
```

However, none of these work (neither in batch file nor in command prompt)

Comment: Why don't you just use a bash script?

Comment: @DavidPostill I am on windows platform.

Comment: https://cygwin.com/, http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys and https://git-for-windows.github.io/ all include bash for windows.

Answer (score 1):

The other quoting does not (according to *[Escaping Double Quotes in Batch Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562038/escaping-double-quotes-in-batch-script)*) apply to the content of a double-quoted string.

You can add double-quotes by substitution:

```
set myvalue="something"
cat %* | gawk " { value = %myvalue% } "
```

Comment: hackish, but works.